# Azure Function to turn on VM timing out with AZ dependency

Tags: azure-functions

EDIT: my real problem here is trying to figure out how to turn on a VM automatically on a schedule. I solved this without a Function. See my own answer.

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://edi.wang/post/2020/6/18/use-azure-function-to-schedule-auto-start-for-vms) on getting an Azure Function to automatically turn on a VM at a specified time every day.

I've set a dependency for the Az Powershell module in the requirements.psd1 file:

[image]

However, when I try to run the function, I get a timeout, and my VM isn't turned on:

[image]

I've double checked the parameters, and they are correctly filled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question but, IMHO using an Azure Function for this purpose is the wrong technology choice. I would suggest using Azure Automation as it's specifically designed for this type of activity.

Comment: @Kane I'm always open to suggestions! I just used a Function as I heard about other people using these to achieve  this goal before. I'll check Azure Automations as well.

Comment: @yesman - could you please tell this - In which hosting plan you created your function app and Is timing out coming for you immediately running the function or after some time?

Comment: Do not post pictures for text messages. This is a Stack Overflow guidline.

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT I can't remember, sorry. I noticed that the VM itself has an option for Automation called "Tasks (preview)" which offers this functionality as well which I'm now trying. It might help you.

Comment: try and let us know if any problem you're facing!

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT

I fixed it, the option in the VM seems to work well. Just checked on Sunday morning and the VM is on. The settings are in the menu of the VM itself. I made a screenshot for you alone: https://imgur.com/a/X54oHjg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more digging. Microsoft thankfully (and finally) added an option to easily start virtual machines as well without needing to use Azure Functions, Automation or anything else.

When looking at the VM in the portal, go to the menu setting `Tasks (preview)` and add a task there for automatically turning on the VM.

[image]